# R display NAs as "." but keep numeric variables

Tags: r

I need to export a data frame of multiple variables into .dta format for someone else's use within STATA. The variables are all numeric, however, when I convert the NA's to "." (the appropriate STATA format) the variables become strings. Is there a way to preserve the numeric variables while exporting a file with "." as the NA values?

Sample dataframe:

```
V1 V2 V3
1  NA  4
2  NA  7
NA  4  3
```

Desired Output: (variables still of type numeric)

```
V1 V2 V3
1  .  4
2  .  7
.  4  3
```

Comment: no there isn't but i'm not sure why you would need to do that. when you export data with missing values, stata should handle missing values the way it always does

Comment: This is neither possible nor necessary. Take a look at [`haven::write_dta()`](https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/read_dta.html).